# I want to implement R10=R11+OxFFFFE in thumb assembly language

Tags: arm, thumb

The immediate value i know can not be more then 12 bits in case of ADDW. is there any way to implement this in one instruction

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't be done in a single instruction.  You'd have to separately add 0x100000 and subtract 2, or some such combination.

Answer (score 0):

Let the tools do the work, BTW immediates in arm (and other ISAs) has been asked and answered here many times.  gnu assembler will choose the optimal solution (usually) using pseudocode.

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
ldr r0,=0xFFFFE
.align

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <.text+0x4>)
   2:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   4:   000ffffe    strdeq  pc, [pc], -lr
```

enable thumb2 extensions

```
.cpu cortex-m7
.thumb
.syntax unified
ldr r0,=0xFFFFE
ldr r1,=0x00010001
.align
```

the other constant was to confirm it is attempting thumb2 extensions.

so no shortcuts you either need to build the value in parts or do a pc relative load from nearby.  Or just code it with pseudocode and get what you get.

a similar constant

```
cpu cortex-m7
.thumb
.syntax unified
ldr r0,=0xFFFFFFFE
ldr r1,=0x00010001
.align

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f06f 0001   mvn.w   r0, #1
   4:   f04f 1101   mov.w   r1, #65537  ; 0x10001
```

could have been done without the pc relative load.

No you cannot implement this with one instruction.

but this:

```
add r10,r11,#0xFFFFFFFE
```

you can...if that helps.